# How to insert an Audio Player in a Post or Page?

Tags: media, homepage

I have a blog which I sometimes use for audio clips. I want to put an Audio Player on the frontpage of my blog.

How can I put the player after the title or make its code part of post excerpts?

Comment: Hi, kadar, welcome. IMO, your Question is off-topic per this Stack rules, check the FAQ. Close voting as such. ...... Search for [plugins in the Repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=audio+player).

Comment: @brasofilo Where did you read _plugin?_ Adding specific HTML elements to specific pages is not off topic here.

Comment: @toscho, a clear mis-judgement... will be more careful with my statements.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake in form of an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Plugin option

When searching for a plugin, it is important to check:

- **Compatible up to**, supports current WordPress version?
- **Last updated**, too long ago?
- **Support**, too many bug reports? Level of support in the forum or in the official plugin page.
- **Compatibility**, if the plugin hasn't been updated for a while or is not compatible with the current WP version, check the previous WordPress versions. Sometimes the plugin is not updated because it *simply works*.

---

### Do it yourself

You are in control of what happens and when it happens.

Here I'm creating a function that will print a Html5 Audio Tag based on two audio files uploaded to any post or page -one `mp3` and one `ogg`.

> *Reference tutorials: [[one]](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3920991/HTML5-Primer-How-To-Use-the-Audio-Tag.htm) and [[two]](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property)*

In the theme template files (`single.php`, `page.php`, etc), put the function `print_audio_attachments_as_html5` like this:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</header>
<?php print_audio_attachments_as_html5( $post->ID ); ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Note that the function is placed inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), so `$post->ID` is available.

**Put the following function at the end of your theme functions file**
`/wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`
<sub>*check the comments in the code*</sub>

```
function print_audio_attachments_as_html5( $post_id )
{
    // Parameters for our search
    $args_mp3 = array(   
        'post_parent'       => $post_id,
        'post_type'         => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'       => 1, // only one file
        'post_mime_type'    => 'audio/mpeg', // Mp3 audio mime type
    );
    $args_ogg = array(   
        'post_parent'       => $post_id,
        'post_type'         => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'       => 1,
        'post_mime_type'    => 'audio/ogg', // Firefox does not supports Mp3
    );

    // Get audio files
    $mp3 = get_children( $args_mp3 );
    $ogg = get_children( $args_ogg );
    
    // If there's any result in one of the get_children, execute code
    if( $mp3 || $ogg )
    {
        // Start Audio tag
        echo '<audio loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">';
        
        // Mp3 source
        if( $mp3 ) {
            $id   = array_pop( array_keys( $mp3 ) );
            $mp3_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); 
            echo '<source src="' . $mp3_url . '" />';
        }

        // Ogg source
        if( $ogg ) {
            $id   = array_pop( array_keys( $ogg ) );
            $ogg_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); 
            echo '<source src="' . $ogg_url . '" />';
        }
        
        // Close Audio tag
        echo '</audio>';
    }
}
```

---

### Related Q&A

- [How to add audio files to wordpress blog and making it auto play?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/67108/12615)

### Useful info

- [Creating a WordPress shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/51840/12615)
- [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)
- [Create a Functionality Plugin Instead of Using Functions.php](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on WordPress.com, you have the [audio URL] shortcode at your disposal.

If you're on WordPress.org, you can install the Jetpack plugin to get that shortcode. The shortcode figures out whether your browser supports flash or html5, and chooses the appropriate player.

There's an alternative plugin called "Shortpack" which just gives you the Jetpack shortcodes if you don't want the other Jetpack features.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a free plugin [Audio Player](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/audio-player/) from the plugin repository.

Comment: An answer should be more than a simple link. Please, check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/185667

Comment: Just checked, at least don't recommend a plugin not updated in almost 3 years and with various reports of incompatibility... :/